# sql server:saving changes to table created

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello everyone I'm using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. When I change my database table and try to save changes I got this error

> saving changes is not permitted.the changes you have made requires table to be dropped and re created.

And I found that by turning off the prevent saving changes option I can avoid this error. But my question is what are the problems I may face in future by turning off the prevent saving changes option? Is there any other method to avoid this problem?

Comment: Yes - the other option is to use T-SQL commands (instead of the visual designers) to do your work - those aren't affected by any of those settings.

Comment: is there any problem if i change prevent saving changes option?

Comment: You might accidentally change something in a table with 100 million rows, and changing that (by creating a new table, copying the data, and deleting the old one) could take a considerable amount of time - but other than that, I don't see any reason not to have this. But again: using T-SQL **commands** is often much easier since you **don't need** to do the whole creating&copying circus .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn off saving change i asume that no change will be made to the table. In my experience, SQL Server Management is not the best way to make changes to an existing table, especialy if got data on it. You will find many cases in wich gives you this error and you have to manualy write the ALTER TABLE to make the changes you want. So my advice is always to use ALTER TABLE. Hope this help.